# Draggable Text on Image using JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, watermark

I need a way so that users can add a watermark text anywhere on image .The way I need it is a text box which can be put on image and they can move it anywhere on image and can change text of it.Any JQuery plug-in ? FYI : I am using JSP but as far as I have coordinates and text from jquery i am fine.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with JQuery Draggable.